# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object: point me in the right direction

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've found many issues and solutions to this online but I'm kinda new and tbh I couldn't make it work. It's probably pretty silly but yeah, I need help :)

- The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.assign (<anonymous>)
    at organizeCategoryData (C:\Users\alan_\Desktop\melonwallet\utils\records.js:59:35)
    at getRecords (C:\Users\alan_\Desktop\melonwallet\controllers\recordController.js:125:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

- C:\Users\alan_\Desktop\melonwallet\utils\records.js:59:35

```
organizeCategoryData(categoryList, amountByCategory) {
    const categoryObject = Object.assign(    /// LINE 59
      ...categoryList.map(category => ({
        [category.name]: amountByCategory[category._id] || 0
      }))
    )
    categoryList.forEach(category => {
      category.amount = categoryObject[category.name]
    })
    return categoryObject
  }
```

- (C:\Users\alan_\Desktop\ironhack\melonwallet\controllers\recordController.js:125:30)

```
const categoryObject = organizeCategoryData(   //// LINE 125
        categoryList,
        amountByCategory
      )
```

Thank you so much!

/edit: forgot to clarify this only happens when I try to log-in with a previously created user.

Comment: What's the value of `categoryList`?

Comment: @Barmar sorry I don't know the answer to that lol. What you mean?

Comment: If you do `console.log(categoryList)` what does it show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object.assign only works with objects.  `...categoryList.map(...)` is an array.  Either put Object.assign within the map (or forEach, since it doesn't return anything).  Or take a look at Object.fromEntries.

```js
const categoryObject = {};
categoryList.forEach(category => 
  Object.assign(categoryObject, {
    [category.name]: amountByCategory[category._id] || 0
  })
);

// or 

const categoryObject = Object.fromEntries(
  categoryList.map(cat => ([cat.name, amountByCategory[cat._id] || 0]))
);
```

Comment: First one did the trick. Thank you so much! Anything I should consider this gonna change?

Comment: Nope, it should create categoryObject exactly as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
organizeCategoryData(categoryList, amountByCategory) {
const cList = categoryList || []; //This will add a check for null and undefined
const categoryObject = Object.assign(    /// LINE 59
  ...cList.map(category => ({
    [category.name]: amountByCategory[category._id] || 0
  }))
)
cList.forEach(category => {
  category.amount = categoryObject[category.name]
})
return categoryObject
```

}

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. I'm getting the exact same error.

Comment: what should be the expected value of `categoryObject`?